# .usqldbproj could not be opened -- 'File is corrupt.'

Tags: visual-studio, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Inexplicably, my U-sql Database and U-sql script project seem to become broken.

And result in an error like this in the output window when submitting a file in the script project to a remote ADLS account with a database project referenced to it.

> yourdatabasename.usqldbproj could not be opened -- 'File is corrupt.'

Notably the database usqldbproj  file hasn't changed (and proven as there are no changes in git).

Building the database works and the scripts validate ok.

Last time I managed to get out of this situation by removing all the assemblies from the project and the deployed remote ADLA account, then re-adding.

It's happened again inexplicably after re-opening the project... this time I found a solution.

This is using version 2.3.6000.0 of the VS2017 Extension.

Answer (score 0):

A simple redeploy of the database to the remote server fixed the issue.

Which is interesting as the error message explains that the local file is corrupt.

I suspect due to the tooling implicitly very closely being tied to the remote database; something during the deploy has triggered what ever was fixed in the background.

It was a little frustrating the first time around, as at the time my database project did indeed have problems causing duplicate assembly names. This time there were no such known problems, so a simple redeploy fixed VS 2017.